# Is there no way in JavaScript to test a string and determine if it is valid UTF-8 content?

Tags: javascript, xml, encoding, utf-8

I know I've asked a few variations of this question, but I haven't been able to find an answer yet.

I'm creating UTF-8 encoded XML from the contents of a forums database. The language I'm using is server-side JavaScript which can retrieve data from the NoSQL object-oriented database and I'm generating XML output from that.

Most of the database content is UTF-8. But for historical reasons (the site used to be ISO-8859-1) some user names (e.g. André) and some profile info have accented or special characters in them which were originally encoded in ISO-8859-1.

If I know which content is really ISO-8859-1 I can simply manually edit their profiles in my browser (which is set to UTF-8 because the charset of the page is now UTF-8) and when I do so the new content becomes UTF-8.

I can see the before and after, because if I look at the user's profile in UTF-8 at first it looks like there is an invalid character which doesn't display correctly. But if I force the page to display in ISO-8859-1 the accented character shows up, and if I switch back to UTF-8 and edit the profile and view it it all looks fine then. So if I can locate the characters I can fix them.

The problem is I don't know how to locate such characters algorithmically. There must be SOME way of doing it, because if I try to load the XML I create all my browsers: Chrome, Safari and FireFox won't load the XML content and report an "invalid encoded character" at such and such a line and such and such a column.

When that happens, sure enough if I open the file in vi in Linux I can see the invalid character there, and I can see whose record it is and I can edit the person's profile and regenerate the XML.

But the browsers only report the first instance of an error and then stop. So I have to do this over and over again, trying to track down each error.

If there was some way of doing a test of the characters, using JavaScript, I can go through the entire database first and identify all the characters which are not valid encoded UTF-8.

There must be - just must be! - some way of doing it. Otherwise how else would the browsers themselves be able to report the error?

I would be grateful if somebody can point me to some JavaScript function or method or anything I can use to check the characters myself and find them so I can go in and fix them.

Thanks!

doug

Comment: You can't load it _anywhere_ as _characters_.  You must find a way to read the raw bytes, _as bytes_ to examine them. The problem is that when you read anything as characters, the storage encoding gets interpreted into 2-byte Unicode characters, whence your "invalid character" messages.  I haven't done enough Javascript to know how JS deals with byte arrays, but that's where I'd start looking.  If JS doesn't have an uninterpreted binary 'byte' type you may have to use a language that does, like Java.

Comment: My version of server-side JS has a special ByteBuffer type which can retrieve and examine the data as raw bytes. In that case is there a JavaScript algorithm I can use to detect whether a sequence of bytes is valid UTF-8? I have no alternative but to use JavaScript for this. Thanks.

Comment: If you can't find a JS UTF-8 library that does what you want, the best place to start would be [Chapter 3 of the Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch03.pdf#G7404) (Section 3.9).  If you don't want to wade through "standardese", the [Wikipedia page on UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) describes it more concisely.  It is not hard to write some simple code that checks a byte stream for UTF-8 validity.  If you get an invalid character, treat it as ISO-8859-1 and convert to Unicode as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I am hoping perhaps somebody can point me to such a JS UTF-8 library. I have been unable to find one and, being a programmer, I am lazy and would rather not spend a long time re-inventing the wheel if such a library already exists. Does anybody know of one? Thanks.

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic on this site.  See the [FAQ] and [Ask].  You can use Google as well as any of us.  I found a whole bunch of search hits.

Comment: Recommendations for help in finding libraries are off-topic on this site??!!

Comment: Yep.  Check the [FAQ].  Here's the text from the "close" dialog: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: Well, let me ask another person this then: Does anybody have a JS function which can validate a set of bytes as valid UTF-8? I believe that is a legitimate question which can be asked here! It is not necessary to reply if you don't have such a JS function or algorithm. But if somebody does and can reply with some information I would be grateful. Thanks.